# Can we implement Alexa Skill to use with our Amazon pay Account in magento 1

Tags: api

In Magento 1 websites, we want to implement Alexa Skills to use our amazon payment account.

Can anybody please share knowledge/steps/guide, how we can implement alexa skill to use our amazon pay account to enable purchases on our website through alexa's voice recognition?

Is it possible for us to implement alexa voice recognition system with Magento community Edition version 1.9.1.0 & so on...

It will be great, if someone who know about that and share his/her knowledge to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.